# sip viewer log import to new project

Tags: java, logging, sip

I have created my graphic java log application which read text SIP logs, and was able to format them for sip viewer. https://code.google.com/p/sip-viewer/ this is a jar file which runs via command line,
How can I integrate this jar file into my existing Java project? In my project I can generate an ArrayList with all the SIP log info ready to be used. I want to call this app and pass my Array and get output in JDialog. any example to import sip viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import sip-viewer jar in you project (easy if using maven)
http://sip-viewer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cli/mavenrepo/

then, integrate sip-viewer in you java class by taken example of the method display in:
https://code.google.com/p/sip-viewer/source/browse/trunk/cli/src/main/java/javax/sip/viewer/SipTextViewer.java